# unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 0'

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a new column in the dataframe, but receive error message after running my code below.

> unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 0'.

```
def calc(row):
       if row['A'] == '1' & row['B'] == '2' :
          return 'R'
       else :
          return row['C']
      
df["C"] = df.apply(calc, axis=1)
```

Anything wrong with my code? Thank you!!

Comment: try change `&`  to `and`?

Comment: Do you mean "and" operator? if yes, change it to and

Comment: Apart from probably needing to use `and`, according to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `&` comes ***before*** `==`. So your expression is equivalent to `row['A'] == ('1' & row['B']) == '2'` and ***not*** to `(row['A'] == '1') & (row['B'] == '2')` as you might have expected... `True & False` actually works...

Answer (score 0):

In summary, you can't use `&` on strings because it performs bitwise AND operation on the result of both statements. If you want to check whether the two statements are logically True use `and`.

If you want to find out more about the differences between `&` and `and`, check out this article by [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/)

Comment: But `row['B'] == '2'` doesn't return a string... An important point here is that according to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) `&` comes ***before*** `==`... So it is actually doing `'1' & row['B']` and ***not*** `(row['A'] == '1') & (row['B'] == '2')` (the latter actually works as expected...)

Comment: That's true. So basically you would need to wrap in parentheses to let python know which to evaluate first.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here...

You could achieve the desired result using the bitwise and operator by making a slight change to the code as follows:

```
if (row['A'] == '1') & (row['B'] == '2') :
```

This is due to operator precedence. In your original code, due to the precedence rules, the first operation to be attempted would have been:

```
'1' & row['B']
```

...which, as you now know, is illegal. This is because the bitwise and (ampersand) has a higher order than the comparison operators.

The *and* operator has a lower position in the precedence order.

It would more usual to write:

```
if row['A'] == '1' and row['B'] == '2' :
```

Due to operator precedence the parentheses are unnecessary

Comment: Or, just remove the operator completely and just do `(row['A'], row['B']) == ('1', '2')`. Or, even simpler assuming strings: `row['A'] + row['B'] == '12'`